# Keep object in context between pages in django

Tags: python, django

A problem I am running into right now in my Django project is that I want to keep a large object in context between multiple pages, so that I do not have to recreate the object every time I access a new page.

My HTML design is that I have buttons that allow me to go between pages using href, but this does not allow me to create a context that allows me to transfer the object to the new page.

I do not want to store the object in the database, since this is something user-specific, and would not be helpful to other users using the website.

Is there some way to make a global variable in the view.py Django file, or some way to use href to transfer context objects, or something else that would allow me to achieve this? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [django session variables](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/sessions/) with [redis](http://redis.io/). It's an in-memory storage that flexible enough to store most data structure you created. For django project checkout [django-redis](https://github.com/niwinz/django-redis).

Comment: No; you *should* use a session var, and you can use Redis as the session backend if you like.

Comment: Sorry for the bump, but it looks like redis is only supported on Linux/OSX. I'm using Windows. Is there another way I could store complex session variables? Thanks.

Comment: I haven't tried the others but please look at the doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/sessions/